# Can I restrict users to a subset of fonts in a Windows Application using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fonts, vcl

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is something like "no, but there are two ways to do it." Is there any easy way to ensure that a person setting up something in my application, storing something like font-settings in a database that will be used across all users of the system, can be restricted to using only fonts common to their operating system?

I don't think what I want falls under any of these options in Delphi:

[image: My Options]

but my ability to interpret VCL terseness has been known to falter... from time to time, oh dear oh dear...

Comment: Doing so constrains the user. You might be stopping them doing something that they want to do, and that makes sense. Let the user's choose their own fonts, and the font is not there at runtime, fall back on a default.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan agreed!  I only asked this question because I wanted evidence that it's either a bad idea or impossible to do what I'm suggesting above.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to tell users which fonts they can use in your application. What about something like large fonts? It's good practice for your application to fit into the user preferences on the machine, not the other way around. People will use a font style and font size that they are comfortable with. If you allow font selection then it is technically possible to build up a list of fonts that are included with the different versions of Windows and then limit your font selection to those sets but I can't see any sound reason to do it.

Answer (score 4):

This might or might not be a bad idea. It depends pretty much on your application. A use case could be if documents need to be exchanged between systems and it is important that only the fonts are used that are guaranteed to exist on another system. A compromise might be to list only the common fonts, but still allow a user to use another font if they enter the name manually.

The Windows Font Dialog does not have such an option. But there is nothing that prevents you from writing your own font dialog that only lists common operating system fonts. You'd have to maintain a list of the fonts that can be selected. But be aware that the availability of fonts can even depend on the installation options of the OS.

You can find a list of the fonts that are included in Microsoft products here:
http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/

Comment: Most document formats include some form of font substitution or embed the font in the document itself in order to preserve the look of the document. I would definitely suggest using one of the standards such as PDF for this type of thing.